# Run app and then download json

Tags: android, json, performance, http, gson

I am making an Android app which working with a content from downloaded JSON file (parsed by GSON). Now, everything is happening in `onCreate()` method after `setContentView()`, which is not very good for performance I think. **First** I want to load and display content of my app (layouts, views) and **then** download JSON from URL. How can I achieve it? Good example is Facebook's Android app.

Source:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_xyz);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
        try {
            URL urlLiczba = new URL("https://xyz/");
            InputStreamReader readerLiczba = new InputStreamReader(urlLiczba.openStream(/*SK*/));

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            LiczbaImprez liczbaImprez = gson.fromJson(readerLiczba, LiczbaImprez.class);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LinearLayout layout = null;
            ImageView logo = null;
            TextView nazwa = null;
            TextView czasMiejsce = null;
            String czasMiejsceStr;
            TextView opis = null;
            LinearLayout lista = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listaImprez);

            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(liczbaImprez.liczba); i++) {
                URL url = new URL("https://xyz/dir/" + i);
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
                JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(reader);
                jsonReader.setLenient(true);
                Imprezy imprezy = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Imprezy.class);

                layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_imprezy, null);
                logo = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ikonaImprezy);
                nazwa = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.nazwaImprezy);
                czasMiejsce = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.czasMiejsce);
                opis = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.opisImprezy);

                switch (imprezy.typ) {
                    case "element1":
                        logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_of_element1);
                        break;
                    case "element2":
                        logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo_of_element2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                nazwa.setText(imprezy.nazwa);
                czasMiejsceStr = imprezy.data + " - " + imprezy.miejsce;
                czasMiejsce.setText(czasMiejsceStr);
                opis.setText(imprezy.opis);
                lista.addView(layout);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong :/.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
    private class LiczbaImprez {
    String liczba;
}

private class Imprezy{
    String typ;
    String nazwa;
    String miejsce;
    String data;
    String opis;
}
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Comment: You should move your networking code to an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: So my root class should `extends` AsyncTask<>?

Comment: Not necessarily. It can be an inner class. Read about it in the docs : [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) , and here is a tutorial : [AndroidBackgroundProcessing](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android calls all methods in Main Thread. You should separate your methods to different threads. for new thread, you should do like this: `new Thread(new Runnable{ your code; }).start();` [click for details](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html). This one example. Another example is using Asynctasks. With this, you can do your some operations in background, and draw your UI's in Main thread. For this, just extend your class to `AsyncTask`. [click for details](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). 
And finally, for parsing data, you can use some libraries, like [loopj](http://loopj.com), [volley by google](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), [retrofit by square](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). These libs help you so much for transmitting data, and even converting API to Java interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.